GloVe embedding for empty string
It looks like the embedding for the empty string in the glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt file that's part of this zip file:
https://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.twitter.27B.zip
is provided on line 38523, but I'm not 100% sure this is what I think it is. I haven't worked with these embeddings much and was wondering if someone could verify that this the case (or not)?

I'm pretty sure that this is the case after doing some exploration. I wrote a function to find the token which has a Euclidean distance that is closest to the token in question and the result was the unicode Cancel Character \x94.
The code used to reach these conclusions are in the following notebook:
https://github.com/MichaelSzczepaniak/WordEmbeddings/blob/master/WordEmbeddings.ipynb
I added the "<>" to the beginning of line 38523 so there would be a token to find. Then I ran the get_embeddings function to create a dictionary of tokens and their vectors.  Lastly, I ran:
word_NN("<>", dict_glove_embs)
and got the result reported above.
